# How can I register nested listview

Tags: asp.net, ajax.net

There is nested listviews and I want to register a button in the second listview to scriptmanager for updateing the updatepanel inside the masterpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a single button you can attach it in the codebehind use ListView.FindControl  otherwise,  if its a list of buttons you may want to wrap your listview in a seperate update panel, then on the itemcommand event on the ListView manuall call Update() on the original UpdatePanel